# JavaScript menu animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have added some JavaScript animation (well i have tried) to my .jsp page. It is meant to allow the menu, menu button etc. to appear and disappear with a click of a button. However, it isn't working.

**Here is the script:**

```
$(document).ready(main);

var main = function() {
    $('.icon-open').click(function() {
        $('.icon-open').animate({
            left: "285px" 
        }, 200);

        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "285px"
        }, 200);
    }); 

};
```

**Here is where i called it in the .jsp:**

```
<body>
    <script  type="application/javascript" src="menu.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

**Here is the relevant HTML and CSS**

```
<div class ="menu">
        <div class ="icon-close">
            <img src="http://cdn.support.sonymobile.com/common/assets/userguide/d2303/ICN-SONY-BTN-CLOSE-NORMAL.png">
        </div>

        <!-- menu -->
        <ul>
            <li><br></li>
            <li href ="#">About</li>
            <li href ="#">Blog</li>
            <li href ="#">Contact</li>
        </ul> 
         <div class ="icon-open">
            <img src="http://www.turkishlanguage.co.uk/images/collapse.png">            
        </div>
    </div>


.icon-close {
    position: fixed;
    left: -300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-open {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.menu {
  background: white url('https://andersonair.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/clouds-blue-sky-blurred-background-backdrop.jpg');
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}
.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
```

Also, when debugging in netbeans, I get an error saying document is not defined.

Thank you

Comment: Without your HTML and CSS code, it'll not be easy to help you

Comment: When you indent properly, it's easier to see that your `$(document).ready(main);` statement is inside the `main` function, so neither ever gets called.

Comment: @KevinGrosgojat Are the additions ok?

Comment: @JasonP I have moved $(document).ready(main); outside the main function however, it still doesn't work.